# We should not publicly say our goals to everyone. But how far it can be actually applied?

Tags: goals

In context of the research* [(reference)](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1111/j.1467-9280.2009.02336.x) by Gollwitzer, that was of *When intentions go public*, which states that: saying your goal publicly will reduce our efforts to do it,

I want to ask the meaning of some specific terms, as well as a one paragraph simplified version of that that research (maybe in 50-100 words) and simple words, and terms, instead of the terms used in it. Because, most of us aren't able to deduce much from the research paper. Some difficult terms are *identity-relevant* , *behavioral-impact* , etc. They should be simplified in an easily understandable english sentences.

But my question is more focused on below questions:

1. To what extent we can push this concept?

For example: When our parents ask, what do you want to pursue? and we reply:

`I want to learn football from Cambridge Football Club, in order to be a good football player`

If we don't disclose the above, our parents might not be convinced sending us to Cambridge; they might think that I'm going there to date a girl maybe!

2. Does wishing or making any weak commitment- such as a daily habit, but not the goal itself- in front of others, will it harm the efforts we make to achieve our goals?

For example, if I said to my friends:

`I am running 100m in morning daily...`

I think that:

The degree to which our goal realization is ruined by a weak commitment is less than that of straightforward saying our goals;

**Research in refrence: Gollwitzer, P. M., Sheeran, P., Michalski, V., & Seifert, A. E. (2009). When intentions go public: Does social reality widen the intention-behavior gap? Psychological Science, 20, 612–618. doi:10.1111/j.1467-9280.2009.02336.x*

---

But, [this CNBC Article](https://www.cnbc.com/2019/09/05/why-sharing-goals-with-someone-helps-you-achieve-them.html), which tells facts opposite to the research. It says, "When the study participants shared their target goal [...], they were more likely to reach their goal. On the flip side, those who relayed their goals to the individual who they believed was a community college student did not perform better. Similarly, the group who didn’t tell their goal to anyone also didn’t see any improvement."

Comment: What is identity-relevant goal? Is it "I want to be a runner like Usain Bolt" or "I will win the race competition (be winner)"?

Comment: Like the former.  Perhaps [this post](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/9462/7001) has more user-friendly language?

Comment: That post https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9462/are-you-more-successful-if-you-publicly-commit-to-pursuing-a-difficult-goal is just an explaination (short) and neither is using simple language, nor addressing my above queries. [ @ArnonWeinberg ]